# c++ reference complexity make me confused

Tags: c++, c

I was reading a c++ code and i came across this problem and i don't know what it mean:

```
uint8 (*const flag_search)[SEARCH_RANGE]=
(uint8 (*)[SEARCH_RANGE])&_flag_search[MAX_MOTION][MAX_MOTION];
```

can someone explain it for me ?

Comment: You must clearly state what exactly you want to ask.

Comment: Dear @Tejendra
I want to know what it means :
(uint8 (*)[SEARCH_RANGE])

Comment: @pooria It's a pointer pointing to an array with element of type `uint8` and size of `SEARCH_RANGE`.

Comment: @songyuanyao tnx !
but what they gave me negative point ? :))

Comment: @pooria You might see the hint of the downvote button, your question is not pretty clear, and lack research effort. You could try to search on web firstly, if couldn't get the answer then ask here with specified question, such as which part of the code confused you, what did you think about it, etc.

Comment: Re: "confused" -- I agree completely. This is horrible code.

Comment: @songyuanyao tnq sir i will do my best next time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint8 (*const flag_search)[SEARCH_RANGE]
```

`flag_search` is a const pointer pointing to an array, which contains `SEARCH_RANGE` elements with type `uint8`.

```
(uint8 (*)[SEARCH_RANGE])&_flag_search[MAX_MOTION][MAX_MOTION]
```

`&_flag_search[MAX_MOTION][MAX_MOTION]` will take the address of `_flag_search[MAX_MOTION][MAX_MOTION]`, and cast it to `uint8 (*)[SEARCH_RANGE]`, which is a non-const pointer pointing to an array, which contains `SEARCH_RANGE` elements with type `uint8`.

Comment: You should add that `MAX_MOTION` in this context is used as an array index, rather than array size.

Comment: so you tell me that there is some pointer that all refer to this array ?

Comment: @pooria Sorry I can't tell you that, it depends on relevant context. What I can tell you is only what it means.